# Setting a countdown timer for a function in Python

Tags: python, timer, copy-paste, countdown, monitor

What I need is to set a countdown timer (for 2 minutes) for the first time initialize function is getting a callback (it will keep getting callbacks in the 2 min period). When 2 minutes end, reset the timer and do something else and when that ends by my "main" function wait for a new trigger from clipboard_monitor.on_text() in order to set again the countdown timer for the initialize function. Is this all possible?

Code:

```
import clipboard_monitor

class ABC():
  def __init__(self):
      .....
      
      .....
  def initialize(url):
      run = ABC()
      toDo.append(url)
      # What I ideally want is to print the message bellow with a counter of how many times this 
      # function has been called
      print("URL has been added to queue for download.")
      # For every element in the list.
      for x in toDo:
        # main() is another function I have that I am using what I got from the clipboard.
        run.main(x)
        # if the last element reached empty list and exit loop
        if x == toDo[-1]:
          toDo = [""]
          break
      .....
      
      .....
  def main(self, url):
      .....
      
      .....

clipboard_monitor.on_text(ABC.initialize)
clipboard_monitor.wait()
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you what to do when the counter is running ?

Comment: I want to have the program standby for 2 minutes (from the time that a preferred link is copied)  in order to create a list of links in that time. After time passed I want to download the pictures from gathered list.

Comment: I think the solution i give in the answer below should work for this purpose. It's unclear as to why you need a timer. Please clarify what function is running and when.

Comment: I updated my answer please see if the code at the end work for you

Comment: I am very pleased with your answer and I will test it ASAP. The thing is that I need a standby timer before the iteration of the list of URLs begin because as far as I am aware off there is no possibility appending to the list while iterate through it. If there is another way, like giving download priority to the copied URLs, then please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: i suggest you make a copy of the list and call deal_with_url only one time with the complete list. so when 120 seconds ends, the next call to initialize will start a new list and a new timer without affecting the old one. but deal_with_url will need to happen in another thread.

Comment: only if you are worried that you will not be abble to copy url when the list is iterated through

Comment: well atm when I copy a URL containing an image, URL is getting edited and then the result image of the link is getting retrieved. My only obstacle is that, I copy a URL/~=1sec using the right click of the mouse so the script can not follow up that speed so I thought about making the list with the timer. Have you got any better idea how I would overcome that obstacle other than having a timer? Is there a way to make a "dynamic" list that will append at the same time of iteration of it?

Comment: Yes you can use a fifo queue to do that. You can call `myqueue.put(url)` in the main thread and do the download with `myqueue.get()` in another thread. Look at `from queue import Queue`

Comment: please consider accepting my answer if you think it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

you can use threading to do it like so :

```
#import clipboard_monitor
import threading

class ABC():
    def __init__(self):
        self.th = None
        self.url_list = []
      
      
    def initialize(self, url):
        if self.th is None:
            self.th = threading.Timer(120, self.timer_ended)
            self.th.start()
        
        self.url_list.append(url)
        print("URL has been added to queue for download. nb:" + str(len(self.url_list)))
        
    def timer_ended(self):
        self.th = None
        for x in self.url_list:
            self.deal_with_url(x)
        self.url_list = []

    def deal_with_url(self, url):
        print(url)

foo = ABC()
#clipboard_monitor.on_text(foo.initialize)
#clipboard_monitor.wait()
```

if we put this in python terminal and we test it with :

```
>>> foo.initialize("test1")
URL has been added to queue for download. nb:1
>>> foo.initialize("test2")
URL has been added to queue for download. nb:2
>>> foo.initialize("test3")
URL has been added to queue for download. nb:3
>>> foo.initialize("test4")
URL has been added to queue for download. nb:4
>>> test1
test2
test3
test4
```

`test1 test2 test3 test4` is printed 120 seconds after the first call to `initialize`